# HTML base64 images are transparent

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I'm currently struggling with capturing an image and displaying it. Basically the site takes a picture with the webcam, draw it to a canvas, then uses the following code to convert it to base64:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

It's then sent to the sql database. I took multiple photos, and all of them have different sizes, so clearly the data is being written correctly. Sadly, when I draw them out, they're transparent. I inspected the page as well, and checked that the base64 of the `<img>` matches the one on the database, and it does, but it also displays the image as transparent when I hover over it. Any reason why this happens? Here's what the start of the base64 looks like:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAYAAACadoJwAAAgAElEQVR4XsS9WZClaXIldO6.

This is how I echo it out:

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '"</img>';
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it's crucial but I think there ought to be a space after `base64, ` and the start of the base64 data

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot and let you know if it works

Comment: seems not having checked

Comment: To no avail. Still the same result.

Comment: When you save the image did you `urldecode` the submitted data ?

Comment: No I did not. I saved it directly into the database. How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: oh, btw - images are `"self-closing"` tags in HTML - no need for the `</img>` - simply end with `/>`

Comment: If you are sending the images to the server using ajax then it's possible that the data is url-encoded so prior to storing the base64 representation of the image you might try, in php, to `$imgdata=urldecode( $imgdata )` etc... just an idea!

Comment: I just decoded it, but it looks the same it does without decoding it, so that's not the problem. I'll keep the self closing tags in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126026/discussion-between-ramraider-and-nodzi).

Comment: Your image appears to be an 800x600 transparent png. Is this what you wanted? Probably easier to debug using a red dot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the following `context` properties of `canvas`

```
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.fillStyle = "white";  // white is background color
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```